# fscanf reads zero bytes and perror("") returns "success"

Tags: c

I am developing, using NetBeans 8 on Ubuntu.

The following code runs but, at the end of the function, scanResult=0, lNumGenes=0 and perror(""); returns success.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int examineCompactFile(char * csCompactFileName, BOOL *isValid)
{
    int     i, scanResult;
    long    lNumGenes;
    FILE * fpCompactFile;

    if ((fpCompactFile=fopen(csCompactFileName , "r")) == NULL) return -1;

    if ((scanResult=fscanf(fpCompactFile, "%ld", &(lNumGenes))) == EOF)
        return -1;
    perror("");

    fprintf(stderr, "scanResult=%d\n", scanResult);
    fprintf(stderr, "lNumGenes=%d\n", lNumGenes);

    return 0;
}
```

When I do

```
od /var/www/Libraries/input.cdf | more
```

on the inut file, I get

```
0000000 000103 000000 000001 000000 005170 005014 051105 000034
0000020 000004 000000 000000 000000 043101 054106 032455 026521
0000040 031061 000063 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
0000060 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0000120 000000 000000 000000 000000 043101 054106 032455 026521
0000140 032464 000066 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
0000160 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
```

I was expecting that scanResult would be the size of a long integer and lNumGenes would be nonzero.

Comment: Thank you.  I made the change to my code to output the values of interest.  I replaced fscanf with fread and that fixed the problem.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `fscanf` returns the number of successful conversions, not the number of bytes read.
2. `fscanf` only sets `errno` if there was an i/o error. A failed conversion is not that kind of error. You shouldn't try calling `perror` unless `fscanf` returned `EOF`, indicating end of file or a read error, *and* you've verified that it was a read error with `ferr`.
3. Your input file appears to be a binary file. `fscanf` is used to extract *formatted* data (i.e. text).

Comment: note that the standard does not require `errno` to be set by `fscanf`, so it would be good to manually zero it before the fscanf call in order to disambiguate errno values being set by earlier functions

Comment: @M.M Since the standard does not mention `errno` at all in its [description of `fscanf()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p16), `fscanf()` is [free to munge `errno` to whatever irrelevant value it wishes](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3):  "The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  [On Linux `fscanf()` does set `errno`, though](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)